# retopology from low to high poly and normal bake issue

Tags: topology, normal-map, retopology

I have made a baseball bat with a grip i blender 2.83.19 and i want to do a retopology of the low poly to the high poly since its not matching the top and bottom of the grip atm.

Screen from low poly[image]

What's the best way to retopo so it matches the high poly? Tried moving vertices of the low poly closer to the edge of the high poly but looks weird when baking in SP.

Looks like this when trying to bake in SP:

[image]

Could this also be a problem with not having enough polys to compensate for high poly density?

Answer (score 0):

> Could this also be a problem with not having enough polys to compensate for high poly density?

Yes, you are exactly right. You can either solve this issue by adding more geometry around the cylinder, or by beveling the area where the distortion is occurring. As a rule of thumb, the more you're trying to get the normal map to compensate for lack of geo the worse it will look.

Here's the all time greatest [thread](https://polycount.com/discussion/81154/understanding-averaged-normals-and-ray-projection-who-put-waviness-in-my-normal-map) on this topic